# How does Flutter use "require" keyword?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've updated to Flutter 1.22 with Dart 2.10, changed sdk constraint to >=2.10, and I still cannot use required keyword. Also I haven't seen this in changelogs. How is that possible?

[image: Example]

Comment: This required keyword is used for null safety https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters (null safety is still not released in stable channel)

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post images of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score -3):

**Edit**

Follow these steps:

1. Make sure there is no linter error
2. run `dart migrate`
3. Fix migration suggestion and apply fixes using the link provided
4. Go to your pubspec.yaml and change dart version  `>=2.12`

Depending on your cases, you may only need step 4.

**I go the downvotes because of this old answers:**

*It is not a keyword, it's a decorator. It means add @
It's `@required` not `required`*

Comment: required will a keyword soon. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/66727#issuecomment-699805516

Comment: See https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters. `required` will need to become part of the language (and therefore a keyword) for null-safety.